# Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

I get an "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error with the below code. It occurs after the music stops and I try to click another song. How do I solve this issue?

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
        paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
        }
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Comment: the selected index will be -1 if item is not found. Is your out of bound -1 ?

Comment: Why don't you use `listBox1.DataSource = files` and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing old items from your `ListBox` when new files are selected. Use the [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to remove the old items before adding the new ones.

The error you are describing occurs because you have more items in your `ListBox` than you do in your `paths` variable.

This would be your new code:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
        paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
        listBox1.Items.Clear(); // added this line
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of the listbox, and bind to a collection of `Tuple<string,string>`.

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path=listBox1.SelectedValue as string;
        // return the path of the item
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var files=openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            var paths=openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
            var items=new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
            if (paths.Length!=files.Length) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            for (int i=0; i<files.Length; i++)
            {
                items.Add(
                    new Tuple<string, string>(files[i],paths[i])
                    );
            }

            listBox1.DataSource=items;
            listBox1.DisplayMember="Item1";
            listBox1.ValueMember="Item2";
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[listBox1.FocusedItem.Index];
```

instead

I am not sure but it seems you focused the item before you play right?.  If so then Try the above code. Also Spooky above made a good point . His suggestion might work as well.
Try clearing the list view before adding a new file.

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
```